# JavaScript and hiding a div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't get my "target" div to be hidden.  When I change the div to hide to "div1" it works, but that is not what I want.  Can anyone see why I can't hide "target" div?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hide").click(function(event){
          var ele = document.getElementById("target");
          ele.style.display = "none";                     
        });
     });                                

    //myItems.length
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#driver").click(function(event){
           $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/JSONV5.php', function(jd) {
           var myItems = jd["items"];
              for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                $('#div1').append('<div id="target">');
                $('#div1').append('<p> Title: ' + jd["items"][i]["title"]    + '</p>');
                $('#div1').append('<p> Description: ' + jd["items"][i]["description"]   + '</p>');
                $('#div1').append('<p><img alt="" src=/uploads/' + jd["items"][i]["image1"] + '></p>');
                $('#div1').append('</div>');                       
              };
           });
        });
     });
  </script>

   </head>  
   <body>
     <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
     <div id="div1" style="background-color:#cc0;">
       DIV 1
     </div>

     <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
     <input type="button" id="hide" value="Hide Data" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, you're adding elements with the ID `target` in a loop, and ID's are unique. Secondly, you can't split elements across `append()` calls, you have to insert "whole" elements, right now you ***are*** hiding the first element with the ID `target`, but that element has no children.

Comment: Right click, inspect element in the DOM, and you would get the answer!

Comment: This is a jQuery question by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use append like it is a string. It is not building the html like you think it is. It is adding multiple elements that are siblings to each other. Second you can not have more than one item with the same id.

```
 $('#div1').append(
    '<div id="target">' +
    '<p> Title: ' + jd["items"][i]["title"]    + '</p>' +
    '<p> Description: ' + jd["items"][i]["description"]   + '</p>' +
    '<p><img alt="" src=/uploads/' + jd["items"][i]["image1"] + '></p>' +
    '</div>');
```

Comment: Thanks a  million! , back to the basics.  I will be creating a new id dynamically.  I just hard coded it to test.  thanks again for all the input!

Answer (score 0):

You $.getJSON() call did not return any data and therefore you never created a div with id="target"

the $.getJSON() call is erroring out with:
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
window.onload = function() {
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

You can also try moving this

```
$("#hide").click(function(event){
  var ele = document.getElementById("target");
  ele.style.display = "none";                   
});
```

after `$("#driver").click(function(event){`.